# How do I do calculation in android shell

Tags: android, shell

I wanted to do something like

`echo "$((123.4/2))"`

But Python and dc is not included in Android shell environment and it is not easy to port to our environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sqlite is a default package which you probably can write:

`shell@android:/ $ sqlite3 <<< 'select 123.4/2;'
61.7`

Answer (score 0):

For simple math you can use:

```
echo $[6/2]
```

Or

```
expr 6 / 2
```

Alternative, **awk** is your friend:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 123.4 / 2}'

#61.7
```

---

**NOTES:**

Bash **doesn't support floating point arithmetic**. Here is what happens when we try to do floating point math with the shell:

> syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

---

**SRC:**

http://www.bashguru.com/2010/12/math-in-shell-scripts.html

Comment: it doesn't work in Android shell, 
$ echo $[6/2]
$[6/2]

Comment: I've tested the code on my phone and it worked. Do you have busy-box installed ? I've updated my answer with the awk alternative.